# How to write to CSV file without using terminal in webscraper

Tags: python, scrapy, export-to-csv, scraper

I need some help. My scraper is now running, and it creates the items.csv file, but only puts the product_name, etc in it.... how do I fix this?
Here is my code as is:

```
import scrapy
import csv

class ProductSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "Product_spider"
start_urls = ['https://www.grainger.com/category/bacharach/ecatalog/N-1z125ev']
FEED_URI= r"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\scraperProject\ScraperProject\items.csv"
# custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ["product_name" , ],
# }
def parse(self, response):
    self.log('I just visited' + response.url)
    yield {
        'product_name': response.css('h2.list-view__product-heading::text').extract()
        #'product_detail' : response.css('').extract_first()
        #'product_rating' : response.css('').extract_first()
        #'product_category' : response.css('').extract_first()
        #'product_company' : response.css('').extract_first()
        }

    Output_file = open('items.csv', 'w') #items.csv is name of output file
    fieldnames = ['product_name', 'product_details', 'product_rating', 'product_category', 'product_company'] #adding header to file
    writer = csv.DictWriter(Output_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for url in start_urls:
        writer.writerow({product_name: response.url(fieldnames, css)}) #writing data into file.
        file_name.close()
```

Comment: you have two functions with identical name. Rename one and show us how you they get called.

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting. I remember throwing that in there just to see if it would make it run and it did, but I didnt truly have a reason for starting another function. I edited it out.

Answer (score 1):

in your settings.py or custom_settings attribute of your spider set

```
FEED_URI="location/csvfilename.csv"
```

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html

Comment: Yash, can you be a bit more specific? I need to create a settings.py and just use that line of code? Or should i set feed_uri="location" in my scraper.py file

Comment: If you are using scrapy project then it would be there in the modules root directory or else you can set it inside custom_settings attribute also

Comment: custom_settings = { 'FEED_URI': "location/products.csv" } it is fine

Comment: I suppose I am not using scrapy project as I do not have anything else in my directory than my scraper.py. ill try adding the custom_settings attribute. Should this be included inside the class or before class statement after my imports?

Comment: @BenP. yes it needs to be there inside your spider class, whatever you have written in the question was right way to define custom_settings

Comment: sorry I was at work. No it did not work. I will update the code above to reflect what I have done. @yash Pokar